# Angular 9 and angular material MatDialog "error this.dialog is undefined"

Tags: angular, typescript, dialog, undefined

In my angular application, I try to catch and show error return by the back.
The calls to the back are done in a dedicated service file (quick-list.service.ts)
example call to the back :

```
getSeries(): Observable<Object> {
    return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8080/serieselk/liste').pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    ); 
}
```

In this same file I have a method (handleError)to catch the error:

```
private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.error.message}`);
    }
    //show error to user in a standard alert
    alert("test "+error.error.message);
    //try to show the error in a MatDialog box to replace the ugly default alert...
    var confdata: Confirmdiagdata = {boxtitre : "Erreur "+error.status, texte:error.error.message};
    this.dialog.open(ConfirmdiagComponent, { //This line return the "this.dialog is undefined" error
      width: '25%',
      data: confdata
    });
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError(
      'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
}
```

With this code, I have an "this.dialog is undefined" error and the matDialog box do not show up
I use the same code for other MatDialog box in my application and it work fine.

In this case, I try to open the dialog in an "Injectable service" (quick-list.service.ts) and in the other case (where it's work) I do it in "component" (seriedetails.component.ts for example)

So my question, is it possible to use MatDialog box here ? and how ?

quick-list.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpClientModule, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { SeriestableItem} from '../seriestable/seriestable-datasource';
import { Confirmdiagdata, ConfirmdiagComponent } from '../confirmdiag/confirmdiag.component';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class QuickListService{

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  [...]
  //some other methodes...
  [...]

  getSeries(): Observable<Object> {
    return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8080/serieselk/liste').pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
  
  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.error.message}`);
    }
    //this.openDialog(error);
    alert("test "+error.error.message);
    var confdata: Confirmdiagdata = {boxtitre : "Erreur "+error.status, texte:error.error.message};
    this.dialog.open(ConfirmdiagComponent, {
      width: '25%',
      data: confdata
    });
    
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError(
      'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  }

}
```

Comment: SO...are you trying to open a mat dialog from within a angular injected service?